# How to passing an `<ul>` over the other element

Tags: html, css, meteor

I want to make my app responsive but I just founded a problem with a `<ul>`, when I reduce the windows he disapear but I want to make it pass over the other elements (look the images)

This is ok : [image]

But this is not ok : 
[image]

He changes side when I reduce the window...

So that's the HTML of the 3 options

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
  <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a id="allMch">All machines</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="rngMch">Only running machines</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="stpMch">Only stopped machines</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the css of dropdown-menu:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  overflow: auto;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    // float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 0;
    // position: absolute;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 9998;
    border: 1px solid #D9DEE4;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #5A738E;
}
```

Comment: try this: `.dropdown-menu {left:auto;right:0;position: absolute }`

Comment: @ManishPatel it still do the same things

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or show a working example?

Comment: It's pretty hard to create a fiddle with Meteor... I'm not able to do it sorry

Comment: view source, copy header html and then copy css that is causing the problem - not that hard

Comment: I founded how to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @nashcheez put an answer with his code I'll mark is as answer but the solution for me was to add this code in the css :

```
.panel_toolbox>li>ul {
    left:auto;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```